# Игнорирование ключевого слова pass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, keyword

Приключилась досадная ситуация, имя одного из полей таблицы, к которой я обращаюсь посредствам sqlalchemy совпадает с ключевым словом pass. Поле переименовать возможности нет. Подскажите как можно обойти эту проблему?

```
engine = create_engine(config.user_base_data ,echo = False)
meta = MetaData(engine)
connector = engine.connect()

client = Table('client' , meta, autoload = True)
client_ip = Table('client_ip', meta, autoload = True, )
ip_tariff = Table('ip_tariff', meta, autoload = True)
payment = Table('payment', meta, autoload = True)

def check_logpass(message):
    userdata = message.text.split(' ') #Парсинг строки введенной пользователем
    login_for_check = userdata[0]
    password_for_check = userdata[1]
    logpass_query = select(client).where(and_(client.c.id == login_for_check, client.c.pass == password_for_check))
    result =  connector.execute(logpass_query)
```

Comment: При обращении к `client.c.pass` возникает ошибка? Кст, `pass` и `password` имеют очень разное значение ;)

Comment: Да. К сожалению таблица уже давно используется и поменять название столбца уже не получится.

Comment: Тогда, попробуйте чистый запрос: `result = engine.execute("<sql here>")`

Comment: в чем ошибка то? тут вроде нет проблем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Обращайтесь к полю через строку](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns) в таких случаях

```
# via string
client.c['pass']
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!